# X11 remote (without ssh forwarding) from Linux to Mac over LAN is speed up

Tags: macos, x11, xquartz

I am running Xquartz on my Mac and want to display a PDF on it from my Linux. Both computers are on the same LAN. I am not using SSH forwarding, just set a DISPLAY to point to Mac. It works but very slow. Flipping a page in `evince` PDF viewer takes a few seconds.

How can I speed things up? One thing I noticed is my Mac 4K display has 3840x2138 resolution. Maybe this is one of the reasons? I also tried to change in Xquartz settings number of colors to 256, but it did not help much.